# Were humans worshipped as gods in Biblical times?

Tags: bible, idolatry

Word "god"  in Bible is not always interpreted as idols but sometimes they are depicted as humans like in these following verses.

> Ex. 12:12 I will pass through the land of Egypt in the same night, and I will attack all the firstborn in the land of Egypt, both of humans and of animals, and on all the gods of Egypt I will execute judgment. I am the LORD
>
> Num. 33:4 Now the Egyptians were burying all their firstborn, whom the LORD had killed among them; the LORD also executed judgments on their gods.

Who are these humans gods that people were worshipping. Anywhere any names of these gods  are mentioned in the Bible?

Comment: I'm really glad you narrowed this question down to "Biblical times". Now we know to look for instances of humans being worshiped as gods dating eternity past to eternity future. Realistically post-creation is probably the zone you are looking for. Or did you mean during the Israelite captivity in Egypt?

Comment: @Caleb  
My attention was drawn to this, when I came across this verse from Ex. 12:12. This and the other verse from Book of Numbers are from the time of Israelite captivity in Egypt and yes, basically I was keen to know who these gods referred there. But it would be of interest to know from other Biblical times whether such practice was in vogue. BTW it is a very common to see this practice in India where any iconic person is treated as god. to quote one case, there is one movie superstar called Amithab Bachhan, who is fortunate to have a temple dedicated to him and he is still living :).

Comment: I had never really noticed the reference to judgement on their gods before at all. Cool question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the word 'gods' here can also mean the kings and lords. That would be a question for [Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

However, it is widely believed among Egyptologists that the Pharaoh was considered a god-king of sorts and a descendant of Ra, an Egyptian deity. [Source 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra#Worship) [Source 2](http://ancientegyptonline.co.uk/ra.html).

I do not know of any other place where *these* gods are mentioned again in the Bible. The closest, similar event I can think of is Nebuchadnezzar in [Daniel 3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel+3&version=NIV) creating an image of gold and decreeing that all worship it. Some have argued that it was a statue in Nebuchadnezzar's likeness, although, the Bible says no such thing.

However, after reading a few books on the topic of *pagan* worship at the time of Christ, emperor worship was somewhat common. Everything from Augustus building up the Imperial Cult, where he was prayed to and "worshiped", however casually, to the Candace of Kush (modern Ethopia) ruling by divine right as the incarnate god. This timeline, though, is about 1500 years after Ramases. Still, the Egyptians had many gods they worshiped, including the Pharaoh, and these verses likely are referring to them.

Comment: Yes you're correct emperor worship was common

Answer (score 3):

While the Egyptians did treat pharaoh as a living human god and his first born their next god. The verses as best I see primarily refers to the false gods [ra and the like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_deities). Each of the plagues were executed against a particular Egyptian deity. [Source wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagues_of_Egypt). Especially the turning of the Nile into blood because many of their gods were connected to the Nile. [Source wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_deities)

> Exo 7:17  Thus saith the LORD, In this thou shalt know that I am the LORD: behold, I will smite with the rod that is in mine hand upon the waters which are in the river, and they shall be turned to blood.
>
> Exo 7:18  And the fish that is in the river shall die, and the river shall stink; and the Egyptians shall lothe to drink of the water of the river.

Comment: This, I think is what it meant, with each of the plagues attacking a false god. The Egyptians would not have missed the significance of it

Comment: Yes, this seems likely. Perhaps if you added a list of the plagues and which gods they attacked that would make this answer perfect.